# Need some advice with second order ODE

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, dynamical-systems, polar-coordinates

I have the following second order ODE:

$$\dfrac{d^{2}r}{dt^{2}}=-2\sin^{2}(\theta)\dfrac{dr}{dt}$$

Where both $r$ and $\theta$ are functions of t (they are polar coordinates). I have been trying to find an explicit solution for , with little success. I have tried using a reduction of order but then get stuck trying to make it explicit. Any suggestions? Thanks.

Comment: I'm not very sure if my approach is right but do check this out:$$\frac{d^{2}r}{dt^{2}}=-2sin^{2}\theta\frac{dr}{dt}$$
Let $\frac{d}{dt}=D$

Thus, the equation reduces to:
$$(D^2+2\sin^2\theta D)r=0$$

Find the complementary function $r_c$ 
$$ m^2+2\sin^2\theta m =0$$
$$ m(m+2\sin^2\theta ) =0$$
$$m_1=0$$ or $$m_2=-2\sin^2\theta$$

$m_1=m_2$ when $\theta= n\pi$

Also, since the RHS is zero $r_p=0$

Therefore, at $\theta=n\pi,$ $$r=(c_1+c_2 t)e^{0.t}= c_1+c_2 t$$

For all other values of $\theta$,
$$r= c_1e^{0.t}+ c_2e^{-2t\sin^2\theta }=c_1+c_2e^{-2t\sin^2\theta} $$

Comment: @SmritiSivakumar: Note that it says in the question that $\theta$ is a function of $t$, not a constant.

Comment: You need another differential equation Maybe you had a system of two DE ?